# What is a word that means "unable to live off"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing about a how some companies lower their wages to the point where the employees cannot live off it. This is what I've got "As the mine's wages plummet to______" I feel like there is a singular word for it. If not, are there any better ways for saying it?

Comment: They do. I just need a word that just means the amount given is "unworkable". Like impossible to live off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Subsistence](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/subsistence)*** may convey the idea:

> - The action or fact of maintaining or supporting oneself at a minimum level:
>
>   - *the minimum income needed for subsistence* (ODO)

You may say: *As wages plummet  below subsistence*, ...

Comment: Although, for me, I would write that as, "As wages plummet below subsistence levels..."

Answer (score 0):

It is not a single word, but one of the most idiomatic expressions that financial newspapers and magazines use is

> **below the poverty threshold (line / level)**

Your example:

> As the mine's wages plummet below the poverty threshold...

[**Poverty threshold**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poverty_threshold) means:

> the minimum level of income deemed adequate in a particular
>   country. In practice, like the definition of poverty, the official
>   or common understanding of the poverty line is significantly higher in
>   developed countries than in developing countries.

[Wikipedia]